# Get response data from Axios using redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm trying to return some data from an API response call, using Axios and redux. However, I'm stuck at how I should retrieve the data. The logging works just fine, but I can't seem to access the data from the promise. Any help would be appreciated.

Videoplayer.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import * as actions from "../actions";

    class Videoplayer extends Component {
        renderContent() {
            return this.props.fetchSong("house"); // this SHOULD return a URL
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <video className="responsive-video" controls autoPlay>
                    <source src={this.renderContent()} type="video/mp4"></source>
                </video>
            )
        }
    }
    export default connect(null, actions)(Videoplayer);
```

index.js (actions folder)

```
import axios from "axios";
import { FETCH_SONG } from "./types";

export const fetchSong = category => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/${category}`);
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_SONG, payload: res.data });
};
```

genreReducer.js

```
import { FETCH_SONG } from "../actions/types";

export default function(state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_SONG:
            console.log(action.payload);
            return action.payload;

        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this should not be necessary since redux-thunk handles this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Redux. Your action creator does not return a URL directly, it dispatches an action and updates your state. Use your action creator in componentDidMount. So, this updates your state. Then with mapStateToProps use this state to reach your data, URL here. Something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions";

class Videoplayer extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchSong("house");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <video className="responsive-video" controls autoPlay>
                <source src={this.props.songURL} type="video/mp4"></source>
            </video>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    songURL: state.yourStateName,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Videoplayer);
```

Change `yourStateName` with what is your state name for your reducer.

Comment: Thank you! I tested it now and it works! This makes a lot more sense to me now.